# Run remote debugging of ASP MVC app by clicking the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I want to create the button in Visual Studio 2015. Clicking this button should lead to attaching to remote asp mvc service. (So I want to do it very simple for developers, I don't want to use Debug -> Attach To Process -> ...)

The real task is to push F5 button so this site will run in remote server (not in my machine).

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: I think you should break your question down into smaller parts. What is the first piece of the problem you want to solve, ask that question and tell us what work you've done already to solve it. Your question as it stands is too broad and there is no good answer.

Comment: Well I could certainly use a feature like that in Visual Studio. Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: You say you want to make it very simple for developers. Doing this is already simple. Are you sure it's not better to just tell developers how to do it?